# NAO Robot - Fingers keep spinning

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, nao-robot

I am trying to use NAO with ROS and Gazebo, but I have a problem with NAO's fingers, where they keep spinning non-stop, what makes the robot shake. This is happening using Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic.

I've tried some of the solutions here, but to no avail. https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual/issues/9

I also tried using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo, but with no success, the problem persists.